# Tomcat7 connectivity issue

Tags: tomcat

I have a test setup( my laptop) in which i deployed a web application using Tomcat 6.x . I usually connect to internet by using tethering option in my mobile.

I tried to access the webapp (http://:8080) using my laptop browser and i am able to access it

But while trying to access the webapp using my mobile browser, i face the Web page not available error.

I am just wondering why i get this error.Since my mobile and laptop is in same network (since it is in tethering mode)

Am i trying something weird? Any idea on this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your laptop is on Linux, check to see if you have iptables enabled. Windows has some type of software firewall as well. Disable it and retry.

Comment: Yes. I am using RHEL(WIndows>VmPlayer>Linux>). The Iptables are disabled  [root@localhost ~]# service iptables status
Firewall is stopped.
[root@localhost ~]#
. I tried tcpdump on my linux and it showed 0 packets captured.